# Vagrant stopped synching folders after upgrades

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I recently upgraded Vagrant to 1.8.4 and upgraded VirtualBox to 5.0.22 (Not sure if it is related) but Vagrant stopped synching my folders.  I tried to downgrade and destroy and recreate the box but the problem remains.

When I run `vagrant rsync-auto` I get the following response:

```
There are no paths to watch! This is either because you have no
synced folders using rsync, or any rsync synced folders you have
have specified `rsync_auto` to be false.
```

This is what I have in my config.yml:

```
...
vagrant_synced_folders:
# The first synced folder will be used for the default Drupal installation, if 
# build_makefile: is 'true'.
- local_path: ~/vagrant/xmd8/www
  destination: /var/www
  type: nfs
  create: true
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded to Vagrant 1.8.1 and ran `vagrant reload` on my vagrant box and that fixed my issue.

I believe I tried `vagrant reload` when on Vagrant to 1.8.4 but I could be wrong.

Comment: It happens the same here!

Answer (score 0):

I had used 1.9.3 (I think) and rsync-auto worked, but some native syncing didn't for a codebase that was ported from Windows. So we had to use rsync for that.

I recently tried 1.9.7 and rsync-auto no longer worked and the native syncing still didn't work.

1.8.6 has functioning native vagrant syncing for the codebase that was from windows. This is the only version we have tried that actually works with the specific codebase (native syncing and not having to use rsync)

Adding this so that it ends up helping someone (which will probably be future me when my computer crashes again and I need to set up another new one).